# How to create a custom async validator in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I created a backend validator and I would like to call it from the frontend in a way that looks like this:

```
  public validate(valueParam: any, fieldName: string): void {
    let fieldToValidate = [
      {
        objectType: "USER",
        type: "String",
        name: fieldName,
        value: valueParam
      }
    ];

    this.userService.validateUser(fieldToValidate).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
```

So the validator should take two parameters as input. My page is composed of many rows and each row has four input fields: firstName, lastName, email and telephone. I didn't use any FormControl or FormGroup in the ts file, I only have and object bond to the html via `ngModel`. So each input field is handled via `ngModel` like this:

```
<input
   type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="user.email"
   [readonly]="isDisabled"
>
```

These inputs are inside a `ngFor` that loops through the rows and for each row creates an input field for name, last name, email and telephone.

Given this scenario, how can I create a custom async validator in Angular and apply it to my input fields?

Comment: You really want to use a reactive form for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend to use reactive forms for this!

Nevertheless: if you are determined to use template driven forms you have to create a directive that implements `AsyncValidator` and register it with the `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` token:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[someValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, useExisting: SomeAsyncValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class SomeAsyncValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    // your validation logic
  }
}
```

Since `validate` only takes the control as parameter you have to either extract the needed information for your validation from the control or provide it via `@Input`s

```
@Input('someValidator') fieldName: string;
```

To apply your validator add the directive to the input

```
<input [(ngModel)]="..." someValidator="fieldIWantToValidate">
```